# Oracle union default sort is weird

Tags: oracle, order-by, union

As you know `union` removes duplicated rows. I thought it removes from the latter ones, but it doesn't.

I found out that **if there's no `order by` clause, Oracle sorts the merged dataset by the first column** and removes the duplicates.

```
select 4,5,6 from dual
union 
select 1,2,3 from dual
union 
select 4,5,6 from dual
```

It results :

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Whereas I expect :

```
4   5   6
1   2   3
```

I failed many times with this, and make the problem simple like the example above.

How do I keep the union sequence without `order by`?

In my real case, the first `select` is full match(`=`) result and the second is partial match(`like`) result.

If I search for **roma** for example.

Full match result : **roma**, partial match result : **aroma**.

And of course full match result should come first. As I said, it seems `order by` the first column of `union` result.

But, as you see:

```
select 'roma' from dual -- result comes out anyway..
union select 'aroma' from dual;
```

Result:

```
aroma
roma
```

**aroma** is alphabetically ahead of **roma**, it comes first.

Maybe I should try `union all` and remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has already been mentioned more than once, you cannot expect rows to be in a certain order without specifying that order explicitly using the ORDER BY clause.

For the problem described in your question, you actually do not need a UNION at all. Use only the LIKE condition to cover both full and partial matches:

```
WHERE
  name LIKE '%roma%'
```

Then use a conditional expression to rank the rows based on whether the match is full or partial, using the DECODE function, for an example:

```
ORDER BY
  DECODE(name, 'roma', 1, 2) ASC
```

or a CASE expression, for another:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE name WHEN 'roma' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC
```

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is....

To enforce an `order` in ANY resultset, not just your specific case, you have to use an `order by` clause.

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2171079) spells it out clearly:

> Use the ORDER BY clause to order rows returned by the statement.
>   Without an order_by_clause, no guarantee exists that the same query
>   executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly you want to see all the full matches followed by all the partial matches with sorting within each set.

If that is the case then you can add a column to your column list as below;

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT 'FULL' as match_type, column_1, column_2 FROM a_table
   UNION
   SELECT 'PART' as match_type, column_1, column_2 FROM a_table)
ORDER BY match_type ASC, column_1
```

To echo the comments above; if you want results in an order you MUST define an ORDER BY. trying to get stuff in the order you want without it can give different results from one run to the next.

Comment: This is a nice try but the difference in the `match_type` values will have the side effect of the UNION **not** removing any duplicates from the 2 subqueries ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Hmmm, true. I was making an unwarranted assumption that the full match query and the partial match query would not return the same results. Seems obvious now that they are likely to do so.